# Xamarin Android Java Bindings library suffers from runtime OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, xamarin, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, bindings-library

Using the technique described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/), I have created a Xamarin Android Bindings library that encapsulates two Java libraries: [ZXing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) and [zxing-android-embedded](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded).

(Yes, I know that ZXing has been ported to C# as [ZXing.Net](https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net) and that there is even a cross-platform wrapper library, [ZXing.Net.Mobile](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile), that supports Xamarin.Forms, but I have found their performance on Android to be poor, compared with native Java ZXing. In contrast, my Android bindings library, which simply wraps native ZXing, seems to be much faster).

When deployed inside a simple single-page Xamarin.Forms app, my bindings library correctly captures and decodes scanned barcodes. However, after a few minutes of operation, it crashes with a `Java.Lang.OutOfMemoryError`.

Using Android Device Monitor, I can see that the Heap Size continually grows until it reaches 128MB, when the crash occurs:

[image]

It seems reasonable to assume that the heap growth is caused by a memory leak, resulting from repeated camera image capture that is not properly disposed.

From the debug output, I can also see that the crash occurs when attempting to allocate memory for a new camera preview, which somewhat supports the above assumption.

[image]

Unfortunately, I'm not experienced in debugging memory leaks (especially those that occur inside the Java implementation of an Android bindings library).

I would appreciate any clues as to how I might diagnose the specific cause of the leak, as well as any recommendations about additional memory leak precautions that are required when using Java bindings libraries from within Xamarin.

Many thanks, in advance.

Comment: The number one thing to check would be you are not releasing native and .Net resources in regards to images. Bitmaps are huge consumers of memory in the mobile env, and you must free those "native" resources when they are no longer needed (Android bitmap's have a Release method that needs to be used, along with `.Dispose` and null'ing things out on the .Net side, even forcing a GC if needed). Also if you are passing image-based "byte arrays" around to get images into Forms, you are probability doing it wrong .  Using the Xamarin profiler would be start if you have access to it.

Comment: @SushiHangover: Yes, this is exactly how I imagined the issue. But I am not explicitly doing anything with images or byte arrays; just consuming the APIs of zxing-android-embedded (which I assume doesn't have memory issues when consumed in a pure Java Android app). My code simply creates a BarcodeView instance (exposed by my bindings library, but generated by the Xamarin tooling) and allows it to access the camera, then handles the event that is raised when a barcode is decoded. Are you saying that I need to manually modify the generated code to include additional memory protections?

Comment: I can not answer that as I do not know your code, but you are creating a `BarcodeView` and that does contain a image...also you stated in a `few minutes of operation`, that would be a leak to me. To say that ZXing/ZXingEmbedded do not cause memory leaks due to user-based coding issues would be a mistake, as there are open/closed issues related to OOM conditions, just because the library itself might be "clean", does not mean your usage of it is, without the app's code to review, I'm would be guessing as to the root OOM issue. Xamarin Profiler would greatly help you pin point the problem areas.